# List with in a List PropertyInfo get properties iteration

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

I had a list as `ProductSpec {id, Name}` and another list as `Product {productspec, id, Name}`.
When I try access the properties of Product into

```
IList<PropertyInfo> properties = typeof(Product).GetProperties().ToList();
```

I am retreving my id and name as a property which is fine but when I try to reiterate a productspec as

```
foreach(var property in properties)
{
    IList<PropertyInfo> properties = property.propertytype.getproperties();
    // I am not getting the productspec columns 
    //instead I am getting (capacity,count ) as my properties..
}
```

So how do I reiterate a list from a list to get the list properties

Comment: What is this `property.propertytypr.getproperties()` ?

Comment: Sorry i edited my question it should be PropertyType

Comment: Could you post the definitions of the `Product` and `ProductSpec` classes to help us better answer you question?

Comment: For future reference to others, the `ProductSpec` property on the `Product` spec class was defined as `public List<ProductSpec> Spec { get; set; }` per a comment by the OP below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is the type of the `ProductSpec` in the `Product` class of type `ProductSpec` or of type `List<ProductSpec>`?  If it is a list you could do the following:

```cs
var properties = new List<PropertyInfo>();
foreach (var property in properties)
{
    if (typeof(IEnumerable).IsAssignableFrom(property.PropertyType)
        && property.PropertyType.IsGenericType
        && property.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments().Length == 1)
    {
        IList<PropertyInfo> innerProperties = property.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments()[0].GetProperties();
        //should contain properties of elements in lists
    }
    else
    {
        IList<PropertyInfo> innerProperties = property.PropertyType.GetProperties();
        //should contain properties of elements not in a list
    }
}
```

Comment: @lazyberezovsky In reply to "Problem was in wrong code (fixed in edit) and in variable name, which conflicted with variable in foreach."  I already acknowledged that the original code contained errors which would cause it to not compile.  However, in the comments the asker states the results he is seeing, indicating that he did not paste in the actual code he is running (which is compilable).  Those results indicate that his property may actually be of type `List<ProductSpec>` rather than `ProductSpec'.

Comment: @lazyberezovsky However, since the question does not make it clear, I will remove your downvote and apply a downvote to the question (which I will remove if he clarifies further or at least gives us compilable code).

Comment: "since the question does not make it clear" completely agree with you and also remove downvote

Answer (score 3):

You need to use same code for property type:

```
var innerProperties = property.PropertyType.GetProperties().ToList();
```

Also rename result - it conflicts with variable in `foreach` loop.

Comment: when i am doing this i am not able to retevie the id and name of product spec... i am retreivng some other properties,,,

Comment: @Bhuvan then you are are getting properties of some other product member, or `productspec` property do not have type which you are expecting it should have. Verify type of `productspec` property. Verify it is public property. Also set a breakpoint and verify name of property which you are getting results for.

Comment: you are right... i am out of my mind... when i seen my code after an hour thank you

Comment: How to add an item for this property .. for example how to add an item in a list which is ina propertry "  Type T = property.PropertyType;" how to add an item in List Type T

Comment: @Bhuvan sorry, didn't get that. You need to create object of property type?

Comment: yes i creatad an object as  Type T = property.PropertyType; and  Object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(T); but i am getting erro when i try to set the value as  property.SetValue(obj, row[item.Name], null); "object does not match target type"

Comment: i am trying to set the value for a class "ProductSpec" which is in property class as   Type T = property.PropertyType; and Object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(T);  But when i am tryin to set the value as property.SetValue(obj, row[item.Name], null); i am getting an error as "object doesnt match target Type"

Comment: This answer doesn't provide anything useful to the asker as `GetProperties()` already returns an `IList`.  This code will behave the same as the code in the original post.  Likely there is something else going on here.  I am assuming the property being hit is actually a of a `List` type since the comment indicates that the properties being enumerated are `Capacity`, `Count`, etc.

Comment: @lazyberezovsky I did check it.  It doesn't compile.  All you did was correct his syntax (variable name and a duplicate variable definition) to make it compile.  I just don't feel that this answer adds anything to the discussion as his code will still behave the same even with the corrections (obviously he had it compilable based on his comments about the results he was seeing).

Comment: @lazyberezovsky That's fair, but would you care to explain why in the comments?  (Note, I don't usually ask that because I think the anonymity of voting should be protected, but since you already told me it was you, I would appreciate knowing your reasoning.)

Comment: @lazyberezovsky Please discuss this under the answer in question...I will take my reply down there.

Comment: Oh my God.. :)  i am sorry the thing is i had not copied my code from VS editor to Stack over flow editor. its a typographical error did by me and i will correct it. Thank you for the precious answer, the thing is instead of an object " public ProductSpec Spec { get; set; }" i created a list " public List<ProductSpec> Spec { get; set; }". So i messed up with the code and i posted my question here.. Now i understood by the below answers  and your comments where i went wrong

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    PropertyInfo[] propertyInfos = typeof(Product).GetProperties();
        foreach (var propertyInfo in propertyInfos)
        {
            var inner = propertyInfo.PropertyType.GetProperties().ToList();
        }

public class Product
{
    public ProductSpec Spec { get; set; }

    public string Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class  ProductSpec
{
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```